# How to listen for onchange even with multiple elements and apply changes to multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a group of inputs of the file type and I need to display the filename in multiple "p" elements when just one of the inputs is given a file. I have already tried to make it work with arrays but it won't function when I try that either.

HTML

```
<input type="file" accept=".doc" id="fileUpload1">
<input type="file" accept=".doc" id="fileUpload2">

<p class="paragraph">Select your file.</p>
<p class="paragraph">Select your file.</p>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('fileUpload1').onchange = function () {
                                var file = document.getElementById('fileUpload1').value;
                                var filename = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                                var pr = document.getElementsByClassName("paragraph");
                                pr.innerHTML = "Selected File: " + filename;
                            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, each element must have a unique `id`. Use `class` if you want to refer to multiple elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" class="file-input" />
    <input type="file" class="file-input" />
    <p class="file-name">Select a file</p>
    <p class="file-name">Select a file</p>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.file-input');
    var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('.file-name');

    for (var i = inputs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('change', displayName);
    }

    function displayName(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        if (!file) return;
        for (var i = paragraphs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            paragraphs[i].innerText = file.name;
        }
    }
}
```